# Avoiding "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): y" in geom_errorbar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am aware that similar questions have been answered elsewhere, but I'm really struggling to get my code to work.

**This is a little convoluted, but the following is my set-up.**

First of all, I worked out the means and standard deviations for all of the data.

```
Reductionstats2 <- mutate(Reductionstats,
                          upper = (AvgRawReduction + sd),
                          lower = (AvgRawReduction - sd))

upper <- Reductionstats2 %>% pull(upper)
lower <- Reductionstats2 %>% pull(lower)
```

This gives two numeric vectors, each of length 9. Each vector represents either the upper or lower standard deviations.

I then went on to plot. This results in a bar chart showing the means, with jittered raw data over the top. I also want to add standard deviations, but this is where things get messy.

```
ggplot(Reduction,
                 aes(x = Stress, 
                     y = Reduction)) +
  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",
           data = Reduction,
           fill = Reductioncolour,
           color = "black") +
  
  geom_jitter(data = ReductionRaw,
               size = 1.5,
               aes(Stress, RawReduction),
               position = position_jitter(0.2)) +

   scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,110),
    breaks = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110)) +
  
  geom_errorbar(data = Reductionstats2, 
                 aes(x = Stress,
                  ymax = upper,
                    ymin = lower),
                width = 0.2) +

 theme_classic() +
  
  ggtitle("Reduction in relative growth rate") +
  
  labs(y= "Reduction in relative growth rate relative to mock-treated plants (%)",
       x = "Stress")
```

My dilemma is that I keep getting the error "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): y". I am baffled because both 'upper' and lower' are numeric variables of length 9.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit the question so that we might reproduce the problem? Just from looking at the code, it is not even clear that the errorbar is causing the problem, it might just as well be `fill = Reductioncolour` that is causing the problem.

Comment: Agree, reproducible example would be helpful. I assume you checked that `Reduction` is the same length as upper and lower; but I agree that it could be `Reductioncolour`. See: https://statisticsglobe.com/r-ggplot2-error-aesthetics-must-be-length-one-or-same-as-data